# Cognos Analytics, multiple columns in crosstab but only one row in measure

Tags: business-intelligence, crosstab, cognos-11

I have a problem where in a crosstab with multiple columns there are multiple rows of measures where I would only like to have one.

The crosstab looks like this:

```
                      |-----Amount-----|     
SITE-----|---PERSON---|----------------|
----------------------|----------------|
SITE1    |  James     |     45         |
SITE2    |  John      |     34         |
SITE2    |  Jones     |     34         |
SITE3    |  Jane      |     54         |
----------------------|----------------|
TOTAL-----------------|     167        |
```

So the first column is the site, the second one people on the site (notice that site2 has two people). The structure is simplified, but you get the point.

what I would like to have is the following structure:

```
                      |-----Amount-----|     
SITE-----|---PERSON---|----------------|
----------------------|----------------|
SITE1    |  James     |     45         |
SITE2    |  John      |     34         |
SITE2    |  Jones     |                |
SITE3    |  Jane      |     54         |
----------------------|----------------|
TOTAL-----------------|     133        |
```

So the measure rows are generated only from the site column, not from site and person columns. This way I can calculate the total amount across sites, not across persons. Currently the duplicate row(s) cause the total value to be higher than it actually is.

Is there a way to achieve this using crosstab, or do I need to think some other approach (second list to show sites and persons) for this use-case.

**<--------------------EDIT-------------------->**

I have mistakenly explained the amount column in my example. I have a table containing sales events and the amount measure should actually be the number of sales events per site. So what I'm trying to achieve is an question: *For a given type of a sales event list the sites where these sales occurred, list the persons working on that site and list the total number of sales events on said site*. So basically I'm fetching all the sales events with some filter (type=something). These sales events have a site where they occurred. that site has zero to n employees. So there's one inner join between sales event and site, and outer join between site and person table. The SQL query returns data like this:

```
sales_event_1|site1|James|type1|subtype2
sales_event_2|site2|John|type1|subtype1
sales_event_2|site2|Jones|type1|subtype1
sales_event_3|site2|John|type1|subtype2
sales_event_3|site2|Jones|type1|subtype2
sales_event_4|site3|Jane|type1|subtype1
...
```

So the crosstab structure is the following:

```
Rows= site|person
Columns= subtype
measure= count (distinct [sales_event_id] for [site])
```

And crosstab looks something like this:

```
                      |-----subtype1----|-----subtype2----|-----total----|          
SITE-----|---PERSON---|-----------------|-----------------|--------------|
----------------------|-----------------|-----------------|--------------|
SITE1    |  James     |     35          |     10          |      45      |
SITE2    |  John      |     20          |     14          |      34      |
SITE2    |  Jones     |     20          |     14          |      34      |
SITE3    |  Jane      |     54          |      0          |      54      |
--------------------------|-------------|-----------------|--------------|
TOTAL-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|     133      |
```

I hope this helps you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new data item

```
total([Sales] for [Site])
```

- Use that as the metric for the crosstab
- Next, click on the metric, and set the property **Group Span** to be [Site]

Comment: I cannot find Group Span property for crosstab. I do find one for list though. I'm using Cognos Analytics 11.0.9. Do you know if this is a property of older Report Studios?

Comment: for 11.x  it is in the section Data (data format, drill through definition, group span)

Comment: @jfp, any luck finding the property group span?

Comment: @jason No I haven't been able to find it. The data section when I select the measure in the crosstab only displays Data Format.

Comment: Are you in lock mode?  You may have to unlock/lock and select the metric
As a suggestion, make this a list first.  See if you can find group span there.
Then convert to crosstab

Comment: @jason I cannot see the property even when the crosstab is unlocked. I created a list and tried to convert it to crosstab, but I got an error. I do use some determinants in the model, but I may have to look into those more deeply to try figure this out. Thanks nonetheless.

Comment: 1) Did the new data item work? The group span just helps with formatting
2) Can you see if the property is available in list form?
3) Can you test this in a simpler model to see if group span is available to the crosstab?
4) Please share the error message, I might be able to help

Comment: @jfp suggestion for Framework manager model.  Copy your fact table at the import layer of your model.  At the dev layer, create another metric that is designed for that level of information.  See if that helps

Answer (score 0):

It is good that you understand your data well enough to recognize that you are getting the wrong results.  It would help you to know that the term is double-counting.

In your case, the grain of the amount fact is on the site level.  I'm assuming that person is an attribute in the same dimension (the relational thing; not the thing with members, hierarchies, and levels, although that is built on concepts from the relational thing (read Kimball )).   Your report is trying to project the query below the grain of the fact and you get double counting.

You ought to have determinants defined in your model (if you are using a Framework Manager package) or column dependency (if you are using a data module).   These are things set up to tell the query engine the fact grains and what objects in a dimension are at which grain, to tell the query engine how to aggregate facts in a multi-fact multi-grain situation, and how to deal with attempts to project a query below the grain of a fact.

Because it would be defined in your model, it would be available to every report that you create and every report that ordinary users create, which would be better than trying to create handling for these sorts of situations in every report you create and hoping that your ordinary users know what to do, which they probably won't.

The fact that you don't have determinants set up that would suggest that your organization's modeller might have let your team down in other ways. For example, not handling role-playing and disambiguating query paths.